Can a Go interface receive any function, regardless of its signature?
EDIT: A couple of the answers have suggested changing the signature of the RegisterHandler function, however as part of the original question I asked if it were possible to further restict the types, not for design suggestions. Changing the signature would change the behavior of the function so it's an unsuitable solution.
I have a function that looks a bit like
func (c *Context) RegisterHandler(f interface{}) error {
    // Do lots of checking to make sure a function was passed in
    // and it's arguments all implement a specific interface
}

func consumer(a ConcreteTypeA, b ConcreteTypeB) {}

func main() {
    ...
    c.RegisterHandler(consumer)
}

which roughly boils down to
var a ConcreteTypeA
var b ConcreteTypeB
a.InitFromContext(c)
b.InitFromContext(c)
consumer(a, b)

Is there a way I can make that interface{} more specific without changing its behavior? If not I'm fairly happy with my solution. I just hope I can cut down on runtime checks and possible bugs being uncaught at compile time.
My current implementation looks pretty similar to above. I have tried to do something like
func (c *Context) RegisterHandler(f func (...InitFromContexter)) error {
    // Do lots of checking to make sure a function was passed in
    // and it's arguments all implement a specific interface
}

But that causes all the existing code to fail because it will only receive variadic functions

You have already found the way with your RegisterHandler(f interface{}), there really isn't any other.
The fact is that if you want to support multiple signatures, you'll also need to have code handling all the various signature patterns you're supporting, so a call can eventually actually be made.
As you already wrote, that'd be a spaghetti ball of runtime checks and in fact also reflection-based checking and calling. It might be cleaner and more intelligible (especially later on) to have something like RegisterHandler(handler interface{ Do() } where your various different patterns show up as implementation-specific struct fields, if that's feasible in your project.

That's what I was afraid of. I do like your suggestion, however I think in my use case you'd just be shifting the mess from the caller side to the calling side. Due to the fact that you'd need to implement a different Do for each pattern. Which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

I'll leave the question open for a little bit to see if I get any other answers and I'll mark this as accepted if I don't get a more compelling answer.

@MasaMaeda, you can use closures if you don't want to implement an additional interface: https://go.dev/play/p/V9rfQajQQJi

@Peter this looks quite similar to the answer eik gave https://stackoverflow.com/a/78691509/5302276. Except your answer doesn't quite do everything the original asked for.

The first question for me would be: Why having a handler as a function with unknown signature?
What you are doing is not different from defining
func (ctx *Context) RegisterHandler(handler func(*Context)) {
    ctx.handler = handler
}

and then just calling
func main() {
    ctx := &Context{name: "test"}

    ctx.RegisterHandler(func(context *Context) {
        ConcreteTypeA{}.InitFromContext(context)
        fmt.Println("OneArgHandler ConcreteTypeA")
    })
    ctx.handler(ctx)

    ctx.RegisterHandler(func(context *Context) {
        ConcreteTypeB{}.InitFromContext(context)
        fmt.Println("OneArgHandler ConcreteTypeB")
    })
    ctx.handler(ctx)

    ctx.RegisterHandler(func(context *Context) {
        ConcreteTypeA{}.InitFromContext(context)
        ConcreteTypeB{}.InitFromContext(context)
        fmt.Println("TwoArgHandler ConcreteTypeA ConcreteTypeB")
    })
    ctx.handler(ctx)

    ctx.RegisterHandler(func(context *Context) {
        ConcreteTypeA{}.InitFromContext(context)
        ConcreteTypeB{}.InitFromContext(context)
        ConcreteTypeA{}.InitFromContext(context)
        fmt.Println("ThreeArgHandler ConcreteTypeA ConcreteTypeB ConcreteTypeA")
    })
    ctx.handler(ctx)
}

only that the latter is much more readable. The problem is that in your example you can only pass your *Context, and the calling function (the context) needs to know what parameters to pass, which makes the choices obviously limited.
So, I would suggest using closures instead.

I should probably mention that this is an inherited codebase and that design decision was made long before I did any work on the project.
The other thing of note is the signature doesn't only affect the handler at call time but it also changes when the code is executed as well or in other words the original implementer wrote this to allow for a declarative syntax in the signature. (and in that case my other solution doesn't quite work either). It's a whole spiderweb of shit.
I think the best thing to do at this point if I'm being honest is to just leave it alone.

But what information can the handler pass when it doesn't know the signature? Can you somehow make more code available?

With refection it's able to get the concrete types and uses that to basically create a DAG where two handlers can be executed in parallel if they don't operate on the same data. The handler doesn't pass the types up the Registration code does. And there are a bunch of rules on the higher order types (Ref, Query, Commands, Logger, etc)
So in other words if two handlers have a Ref[int] they must be executed in sequence, but two handlers that have Ref[int] and Ref[string] respectively can be done in parallel. I could create a closure and pass in the types but that would be redundant.

If you use reflection anyways, any seems like the proper choice. Also, it seems like you are building some kine of dependency injection framework. As said, it's hard to know without seeing more code.

I've kinda came up with a close solution. It's ugly but it appears to work the way I expect it to. It does satisfy the requirement that the original handler code doesn't have to be edited. And all the registration code is in one place so this should be significantly easier to handle than change all the functions themselves.
I'm not completely satisfied but I think that this is a better solution than I had before handling all this at runtime. It does make the registration code significantly noisier though. Hopefully there is a better middle ground to be found.
package main

import "fmt"

type Handler interface {
    GenerateHandler() func(*Context)
}

type Context struct {
    name    string
    handler func(*Context)
}

func (ctx *Context) RegisterHandler(handler Handler) {
    ctx.handler = handler.GenerateHandler()
}

type InitFromContext interface {
    InitFromContext(ctx *Context)
}

type ConcreteTypeA struct{}
type ConcreteTypeB struct{}

func (c ConcreteTypeA) InitFromContext(ctx *Context) {
    fmt.Println("ConcreteTypeA InitFromContext", ctx.name)
}

func (c ConcreteTypeB) InitFromContext(ctx *Context) {
    fmt.Println("ConcreteTypeB InitFromContext", ctx.name)
}

type OneArgHandler[T InitFromContext] func(a T)

// These new functions are so we can get type errasure.
// Go doesn't support this for types only for functions
func NewOneArgHandler[T InitFromContext](
    f func(a T),
) OneArgHandler[T] {
    return OneArgHandler[T](f)
}

func (f OneArgHandler[T]) GenerateHandler() func(*Context) {
    return func(ctx *Context) {
        var a T
        a.InitFromContext(ctx)
        f(a)
    }
}

type TwoArgHandler[T, T2 InitFromContext] func(a T, b T2)

func NewTwoArgHandler[T, T2 InitFromContext](
    f func(a T, b T2),
) TwoArgHandler[T, T2] {
    return TwoArgHandler[T, T2](f)
}

func (f TwoArgHandler[T, T2]) GenerateHandler() func(*Context) {
    return func(ctx *Context) {
        var a T
        a.InitFromContext(ctx)
        var b T2
        b.InitFromContext(ctx)
        f(a, b)
    }
}

type ThreeArgHandler[T, T2, T3 InitFromContext] func(a T, b T2, c T3)

func NewThreeArgHandler[T, T2, T3 InitFromContext](
    f func(a T, b T2, c T3),
) ThreeArgHandler[T, T2, T3] {
    return ThreeArgHandler[T, T2, T3](f)
}

func (f ThreeArgHandler[T, T2, T3]) GenerateHandler() func(*Context) {
    return func(ctx *Context) {
        var a T
        a.InitFromContext(ctx)
        var b T2
        b.InitFromContext(ctx)
        var c T3
        c.InitFromContext(ctx)
        f(a, b, c)
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx := &Context{name: "test"}
    ctx.RegisterHandler(NewOneArgHandler(func(a ConcreteTypeA) {
        fmt.Println("OneArgHandler ConcreteTypeA")
    }))
    ctx.handler(ctx)
    ctx.RegisterHandler(NewOneArgHandler(func(a ConcreteTypeB) {
        fmt.Println("OneArgHandler ConcreteTypeB")
    }))
    ctx.handler(ctx)
    ctx.RegisterHandler(
        NewTwoArgHandler(func(a ConcreteTypeA, b ConcreteTypeB) {
            fmt.Println("TwoArgHandler ConcreteTypeA ConcreteTypeB")
        }),
    )
    ctx.handler(ctx)
    ctx.RegisterHandler(
        NewThreeArgHandler(
            func(a ConcreteTypeA, b ConcreteTypeB, c ConcreteTypeA) {
                fmt.Println("ThreeArgHandler ConcreteTypeA ConcreteTypeB ConcreteTypeA")
            },
        ),
    )
    ctx.handler(ctx)
}


